# decision tree rpart via caret giving ROC of 0.5

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret, rpart

If I understand ROC correctly 0.5 is a null model with 0 predictive power. I'm using the same data to fit a logistic regression with ROC of 0.64 so I'm presuming there is some predictive ability in the data.

I'm wondering if I just have my configuration incorrect somewhere:

```
## tuning & parameters
set.seed(123)
train_control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  savePredictions = TRUE,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = my_summary
)

linear_model = train(
  x = training_data %>% select(-Avg_Load_Time),
  y = target,
  trControl = train_control,
  method = "glm", # logistic regression
  family = "binomial",
  metric = "ROC"
)
```

Gives ROC of 0.64.

Then I tried a tree:

```
tree_model = train(
  x = training_data %>% select(-Avg_Load_Time),
  y = target,
  trControl = train_control,
  method = "rpart", # decision tree
  metric = "ROC",
  tuneLength = 20
)
```

Gives ROC of 0.5

Here are all the various evaluation metrics for these two models:

```
> summary(results)

Call:
summary.resamples(object = results)

Models: logit, tree 
Number of resamples: 100 

Accuracy 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.9817212 0.9824695 0.9824695 0.9823225 0.9824695 0.9824829    0
tree  0.9817352 0.9824695 0.9824695 0.9823226 0.9824695 0.9824695    0

AUC 
           Min.   1st Qu.   Median      Mean   3rd Qu.     Max. NA's
logit 0.9867658 0.9888867 0.990663 0.9896725 0.9907191 0.991328    0
tree  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000    0

F 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.9907763 0.9911572 0.9911572 0.9910824 0.9911572 0.9911640    0
tree  0.9907834 0.9911572 0.9911572 0.9910825 0.9911572 0.9911572    0

Kappa 
      Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
logit    0       0      0    0       0    0    0
tree     0       0      0    0       0    0    0

Precision 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.9817212 0.9824695 0.9824695 0.9823225 0.9824695 0.9824829    0
tree  0.9817352 0.9824695 0.9824695 0.9823226 0.9824695 0.9824695    0

Recall 
      Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
logit    1       1      1    1       1    1    0
tree     1       1      1    1       1    1    0

ROC 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.5741854 0.6315647 0.6589653 0.6448492 0.6685837 0.6909468    0
tree  0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000    0

Sens 
      Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
logit    1       1      1    1       1    1    0
tree     1       1      1    1       1    1    0

Spec 
      Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
logit    0       0      0    0       0    0    0
tree     0       0      0    0       0    0    0
```

AUC is prAUC and ROC is ROC AUC. The numbers for logit regression fit with expectations but for the tree it looks like something is off since ROC is 0.5. Is there something flawed with my train() configuration?

Some more details on my data:

x is the data frame with target joined onto training data

```
summary(x)
 userTypeNewVisitor deviceCategorydesktop Traffic_TypePaidTraffic Log_Avg_Load_Time Avg_Load_Time    target   
 Min.   :0.0000     Min.   :0.0000        Min.   :0.0000          Min.   :-1.4271   Min.   :  0.24   X0:6446  
 1st Qu.:0.0000     1st Qu.:0.0000        1st Qu.:0.0000          1st Qu.: 0.8416   1st Qu.:  2.32   X1: 116  
 Median :0.0000     Median :0.0000        Median :0.0000          Median : 1.4516   Median :  4.27            
 Mean   :0.3478     Mean   :0.2138        Mean   :0.4139          Mean   : 1.5607   Mean   : 10.18            
 3rd Qu.:1.0000     3rd Qu.:0.0000        3rd Qu.:1.0000          3rd Qu.: 2.1668   3rd Qu.:  8.73            
 Max.   :1.0000     Max.   :1.0000        Max.   :1.0000          Max.   : 6.1834   Max.   :484.62
```

And here is the dput just for where the target class is true:

```
> dput(glimpse(x %>% filter(target == "X1")))
Observations: 116
Variables: 6
$ userTypeNewVisitor      <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, …
$ deviceCategorydesktop   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Traffic_TypePaidTraffic <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
$ Log_Avg_Load_Time       <dbl> 0.58221562, 0.97077892, 0.98954119, 1.80500470, 1.37371558, 2.38508631, 2.47232787, 2.00417906, 1.43270073, 1.19694819, 0.44468582, 1.68824909, 1.34025042, 1.06815308, 1.28923265, 1.6…
$ Avg_Load_Time           <dbl> 1.79, 2.64, 2.69, 6.08, 3.95, 10.86, 11.85, 7.42, 4.19, 3.31, 1.56, 5.41, 3.82, 2.91, 3.63, 4.99, 1.29, 4.60, 8.98, 2.59, 3.01, 5.18, 4.73, 3.75, 3.40, 5.46, 4.65, 3.10, 5.78, 5.81, 1…
$ target                  <fct> X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1, X1,…
structure(list(userTypeNewVisitor = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0), deviceCategorydesktop = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Traffic_TypePaidTraffic = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0), Log_Avg_Load_Time = c(0.582215619852664, 0.970778917158225, 
0.989541193613748, 1.80500469597808, 1.37371557891303, 2.38508631450579, 
2.47232786758114, 2.00417905717929, 1.43270073393405, 1.19694818938897, 
0.444685821261446, 1.68824909285839, 1.34025042261848, 1.0681530811834, 
1.28923264827676, 1.60743590976343, 0.254642218373581, 1.52605630349505, 
2.19499988231411, 0.951657875711446, 1.10194007876078, 1.64480505627139, 
1.55392520250384, 1.32175583998232, 1.22377543162212, 1.69744878975681, 
1.53686721959926, 1.1314021114911, 1.75440368268429, 1.75958057086382, 
2.46640317822344, 1.12167756159911, 1.41827740697294, -0.0202027073175195, 
1.25276296849537, 1.43508452528932, 2.75110969056266, 0.741937344729377, 
0.405465108108164, 0.78845736036427, 1.45161382724053, 2.00552585872967, 
1.47704872438835, 2.797890905102, 1.11841491596429, 0.86288995514704, 
1.9473377010465, 0.662687973075237, 0.392042087776024, 1.0952733874026, 
0.978326122793608, 1.66770682055808, 1.52822785700856, 1.34807314829969, 
1.51512723296286, 1.3609765531356, 0.85015092936961, 1.41098697371026, 
0.824175442966349, 0.854415328156068, 1.20896034583698, 0.524728528934982, 
1.07840958135059, -0.2484613592985, 0.641853886172395, 1.68824909285839, 
1.29198368164865, 0.751416088683921, 1.16627093714192, 1.83098018238134, 
1.45161382724053, 1.5953389880546, 0.802001585472027, 1.58719230348678, 
1.34025042261848, 1.25561603747777, 1.56024766824333, 0.828551817566148, 
0.582215619852664, 2.23964529322017, 0.871293365943419, 1.87793716546911, 
1.10856261952128, 1.69193913394584, 1.880990602956, 1.35066718347674, 
0.774727167552368, 1.36609165380237, 2.10169215061466, 1.24126858906963, 
0.904218150639886, 1.26412672714568, 1.67896397508271, 0.350656871613169, 
0.431782416425538, 1.54115907168081, 1.45161382724053, 1.34286480319255, 
1.25276296849537, 1.4747630091075, 1.51072193949494, 1.10194007876078, 
0.908258560176891, 2.36273901581379, 1.42791603581071, 2.10778601468898, 
0.615185639090233, 1.24703229378638, 0.810930216216329, 1.19392246847243, 
1.37371557891303, 1.56653041142282, 1.07840958135059, 0.27002713721306, 
1.55180879959746, 0.797507195884188), Avg_Load_Time = c(1.79, 
2.64, 2.69, 6.08, 3.95, 10.86, 11.85, 7.42, 4.19, 3.31, 1.56, 
5.41, 3.82, 2.91, 3.63, 4.99, 1.29, 4.6, 8.98, 2.59, 3.01, 5.18, 
4.73, 3.75, 3.4, 5.46, 4.65, 3.1, 5.78, 5.81, 11.78, 3.07, 4.13, 
0.98, 3.5, 4.2, 15.66, 2.1, 1.5, 2.2, 4.27, 7.43, 4.38, 16.41, 
3.06, 2.37, 7.01, 1.94, 1.48, 2.99, 2.66, 5.3, 4.61, 3.85, 4.55, 
3.9, 2.34, 4.1, 2.28, 2.35, 3.35, 1.69, 2.94, 0.78, 1.9, 5.41, 
3.64, 2.12, 3.21, 6.24, 4.27, 4.93, 2.23, 4.89, 3.82, 3.51, 4.76, 
2.29, 1.79, 9.39, 2.39, 6.54, 3.03, 5.43, 6.56, 3.86, 2.17, 3.92, 
8.18, 3.46, 2.47, 3.54, 5.36, 1.42, 1.54, 4.67, 4.27, 3.83, 3.5, 
4.37, 4.53, 3.01, 2.48, 10.62, 4.17, 8.23, 1.85, 3.48, 2.25, 
3.3, 3.95, 4.79, 2.94, 1.31, 4.72, 2.22), target = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("X0", "X1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-116L), class = "data.frame")
```

I added parameter to trainControl `sampling = "up"`, here are rthe results after that:

```
> summary(results)

Call:
summary.resamples(object = results)

Models: logit, tree 
Number of resamples: 100 

Accuracy 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.5907012 0.6009139 0.6051829 0.6071289 0.6051829 0.6336634    0
tree  0.9207317 0.9329779 0.9375476 0.9352332 0.9420732 0.9428354    0

AUC 
            Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. NA's
logit 0.98673234 0.98959375 0.98968944 0.98978234 0.99070965 0.99218652    0
tree  0.04041049 0.04273307 0.04570514 0.04832824 0.05028082 0.06251166    0

F 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.7399516 0.7473481 0.7502411 0.7522966 0.7507218 0.7732202    0
tree  0.9586974 0.9652723 0.9677419 0.9664735 0.9701023 0.9705536    0

Kappa 
              Min.      1st Qu.      Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. NA's
logit  0.005937197  0.013162973 0.017745938 0.01612017 0.01831303 0.02544174    0
tree  -0.008827835 -0.001674637 0.001420743 0.01140350 0.01691454 0.04918470    0

Precision 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.9845361 0.9855769 0.9885204 0.9876619 0.9885932 0.9910828    0
tree  0.9820993 0.9823293 0.9824281 0.9826814 0.9825119 0.9840383    0

Recall 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.5927075 0.6007752 0.6035687 0.6076647 0.6051202 0.6361521    0
tree  0.9363848 0.9487975 0.9534884 0.9508218 0.9565555 0.9588829    0

ROC 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.5772759 0.6391583 0.6480283 0.6462557 0.6620063 0.7048099    0
tree  0.4912470 0.4990226 0.5019395 0.5105331 0.5160169 0.5444396    0

Sens 
           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.5927075 0.6007752 0.6035687 0.6076647 0.6051202 0.6361521    0
tree  0.9363848 0.9487975 0.9534884 0.9508218 0.9565555 0.9588829    0

Spec 
            Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
logit 0.47826087 0.50000000 0.60869565 0.57826087 0.60869565 0.6956522    0
tree  0.04347826 0.04347826 0.04347826 0.06884058 0.08333333 0.1304348    0
```

Was adding `sampling = "up"` a appropriate course of action?

Comment: Something looks off here, you have a sensitivity of 1 and specificity of 0 for both models. Have you tried inspecting what predictions the models are making for individual cases?

Comment: @Marius I've added a summary of the entire data frame as well as dput of just the target class being true. My data are imbalanced for sure. I tried adding a parameter to my trainControl object: sampling = up. Results appended to my post

Comment: try tuning the threshold for predictions, and see if it makes a difference. https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/thresholder.html